# Revit python design automation

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

Out of curiosity, could you bundle IronPython with the AppBundle for design automation? So you could use something like https://github.com/cridder/revitpythonloader to run a python script?

Answer (score 0):

If it can be self-contained inside a zip file and doesn't exceed the size limit of the API for AppBundle, I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work :)